# System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data - after publishing site

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, httpexception

I have written the following code for login:

```
 Session["IsLogin"] = false;
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        if (txtPassword.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            // Display Error
        }
        else
        {
            string Pwd = config.AppSettings.Settings["PWD"].Value.ToString();
            FormsAuthenticationTicket formAuthTk = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Pwd);
            string strDcryptedPwd = formAuthTk.Name.Trim().ToString();
            if (txtPassword.Text.Trim() == strDcryptedPwd)
            {
                Session["IsLogin"] = true;
                Response.Redirect("AnyPage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                // Error, Wrong password
            }
        }
```

Which is running fine while running through Visual studio. But when I published it it is showing the below error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data

NOTE:

1. I publish the application on the
   same server on which I am developing
   the site.
2. I have tried EnableViewStateMAC =
   false on page level. [Login Page]

What is the reson of this error? Why it is only appears when I have published the site?

Comment: In some cases I am getting error while running it from VS2008. The error comes at the line `FormsAuthenticationTicket formAuthTk = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Pwd); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the way to encrypt the string and the problem disapperars. I have no idea about the reason of the error, but I resolved it like this.
Hope it will help to others, who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to declare the config in the way you did, just use Configuration.AppSettings["PWD"].ToString()...

Comment: I did the same and I got this error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Configuration.AppSettings.get'` **while compiling website**

Answer (score 0):

see here:

[How to: Read Application Settings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx)

Comment: I am now reading the value in the same way which the above link is specified. But the error persist. Any suggestion?